# Error Reading Serialized Object? WP7

Tags: serialization, exception, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am reading an object from Isolated Storage with the following code:

```
public static T Load<T>(string name) where T : class, new()
    {
        T loadedObject = null;
        using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream storageFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(name, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, storageFile))
        {
            if (storageFileStream.Length > 0)
            {
                    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                    loadedObject = serializer.ReadObject(storageFileStream) as T; //####Error Here####
            }
            if (loadedObject == null)
            {
                loadedObject = new T();
            }
        }
```

Upon reading my object I am getting a SecurityException which reads

"The type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song' cannot be deserialized in partial trust because it does not have a public parameterless constructor."

My object class being read contains a Song property which is throwing the above error.

Is there some way around this? I would like for my Song property to be stored with my object. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your goal?

1. Do you want to just play a song in the app?
2. Do you create your song in the app?
3. Do you want to have access to the song library?
4. Do you want to get the song from the web?

@1 Just add a song to your conent in your project. no need to use serialization. 
@2 Use memory stream to mainulate it. save it and then load the stream. Use MediaElement.SetSource(Stream stream) 
@3 Use [MediaPlayerLauncher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.mediaplayerlauncher%28VS.92%29.aspx)  
@4 Song song = Song.FromUri..

You need to store it in a diffrent way. Exception explatins pretty much all why a Song is a bad choice in this case.

Look at this example.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/3080021c-3960-49a0-ac5b-ebf2680592e1

Comment: I am storing an object which contains a Song property. When I read the object from Isolated storage I require the Song property to be read.

Comment: Are you saying there is no way around this using my current method?

Comment: Instead of storing a Song (I realize now why it won't allow me to do that) I stored the index in my MediaLibrary.Songs. Now I can load up my objects and reset all the Song Property.